# In Fabric JS, how to reactivate the canvas that is deactivated by canvas.deactivateAll();

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I deactivated the canvas using the function deactivateAll().
How can I reactivate it?

If that is not possible, what is the alternative way to deactivate and reactive the canvas?

Comment: in newer version `deactivateAll` is removed. so avoid using that.

Comment: @Durga, Thank you for the info. Is there any alternative to that?

Comment: You want for group or only single object?

Comment: @Durga, For a group.